# Quem faz a conexão com o banco de dados no SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, banco-de-dados, conexão, sqlalchemy

Eu tenho um app que usa o ORM do SQLAlchemy, porém estou confuso em relação à essa conexão.

É o SQLAlchemy ou o driver de conexão (no meu caso o psycopg2) que realmente se conecta ao banco de dados?

Comment: O SQLAlchemy faz a conexão usando o `create_engine`. Para importar o método use `from sqlalchemy import create_engine`.

Comment: O SQLAlchemy não faz a conexão, na verdade e é uma camada de abstração sobre banco de dados relacionais que mapeia tabelas em objetos. Para fazer isso ele usa um classe Dialect que é um invólucro sobre o driver, no seu caso o driver PostgreSQL(psycopg2). Se você olhar a fonte do [SQLAlchemy](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/tree/master/lib/sqlalchemy/dialects) verá que os drivers de conexão de alguns DBMS estão inclusos para os que não estão inclusos no pacote é fornecida uma [interface ODBC](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/tree/master/lib/sqlalchemy/connectors).